# How can I set an environment variable before each build on heroku?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app, rollbar

I have a `create-react-app` and I need an automated way to set an different environment variables before each build.
My goal is to set a `code_version` for Rollbar.

I tried the following:

1. `"heroku-prebuild": "heroku config:set REACT_APP_ROLLBAR_CODE_VERSION=test123 && sh upload-source-maps-script.sh"`
   error message: `/bin/sh: 1: config:set: not found`
2. `"heroku-prebuild": "sh upload-source-maps-script.sh"` and from within sh file `heroku config:set REACT_APP_ROLLBAR_CODE_VERSION=test123`
   error: no error message, but config var is not set
3. Also from within sh file `export REACT_APP_ROLLBAR_CODE_VERSION=test123`

Comment: You can do something like this: https://github.com/NNTin/discord-twitter-bot/blob/master/app.json --- else it is just not possible. You cannot set an env variable during build. Env variables is something you set externally before or after the build. Be it through the Heroku dashboard (see Aravind answer) or through the CLI (`heroku config:set ...`)

Answer (score 0):

```
 heroku config:set <YOUR_KEY>=<YOUR_VALUE>
```